# Why does my Website Pictures does not show on Facebook thumbnail when i share it?

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have An Opencart Shop, I made a good few changes on it, then now every time I try sharing a page from my website it gets everything but my Images.

Here is my header

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ct1.addthis.com/static/r07/auth016.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//ct1.addthis.com/static/r07/widget119.css" media="all">
  <style media="screen"></style>

  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
  <meta property="og:title" content="3.5mm to 3.5mm Plug Audio Cable - (120cm)">
  <meta property="og:type" content="website">
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="IT Bargain">
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://grabyourbargain.com/image/data/sku_283716_1.jpg">
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://grabyourbargain.com/index.php?route=product/product&amp;product_id=2554">
  <meta property="og:description" content=" My Description">
```

I have used the debug FB tool already it has my picture there but it doesn't show me i can click and it will open but it doesn't actually show me at the debugger page. could someone Help me plz!

[Here is the link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fgrabyourbargain.com%2Fpp2554-3%25205mm%2520to%25203%25205mm%2520plug%2520audio%2520cable%2520%2520%2520%2520120cm) of the results of FB debugger for my page

Answer (score 1):

Because you've entered the wrong image path, http://grabyourbargain.com/image/data/sku_283716_1.jpg is not accesible, on a quick check you have entered the wrong path (cache - folder is missing), and also the size of the product image, like this: http://grabyourbargain.com/image/cache/data/sku_283716_1-350x350.jpg

Comment: Sorry But i have no idea how to change because its getting from my database that url is there any other way ?

Comment: How you added the FB meta tags? You used a plugin or it is a default option?

Comment: i used a plugin TZ_opengraph_meta.xml, i'v managed to go to the folder cache but it still tries to get the picture without the 350x350

Comment: This is a bug in the plug in you used. Ask them to fix it or change the plugin, there are many free ones availabe. I could fix it for you but I do not have access to the plugin source code.

Comment: i could give you the code if u could have a look for me would be amazing help

Comment: Do a google search and send it to my email, I will post the fix here.